# Modifying spring framework as per my needs

Tags: java, spring

I need to do develop a wrapper on top of spring framework. Details are as follows:

There will be one file called as template

```
<beans>
   <bean  class"com.sample.SampleClass">
          <property name="abc" identifier="id100" > defaultValue </property>
          <property name="abc" identifier="id101" >  </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Now there will be many value files
Contents of Value files will be:

```
id100={ someValue}
id101={ overidingValue}
```

Now at run time new bean will be created for each value file. So value files will create one separate bean for each value file by overriding values from value file.

How can i go about developing such framework?
Any pointers?

This is just my very basic idea.

How can i use BeanFactory as mentioned by Alex in this context?

Comment: `I don't understand your question` is a good answer.

Comment: @Alex have u understood it now?

Comment: The idea is there will be one template which supplies default values.And each of the value file will overide the template default value. I dont want to have entire xml file to be copied each time .I want to have simple value files which the user can edit quickly

Comment: Ask yourself whether Spring is the right library to build upon? Why are you using it if you want to do something that is so different from how spring works?

Comment: @HieryNomus so that i can use reuse spring framework.My requirements are similar to what spring does but there are some slight modifications that i need.Hence i was asking for guidance from experts @ stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use BeanFactory. It can implement any logic your want and get its configuration via `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: Thanks for replying.Can you please provide some details

Comment: I checked PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.But it can use to overide values by using some placeholder in original config file.But the problem is i need to create a separate bean for each value files.How can i go about it?